# Google Spreadsheets function to filter by date and count text strings in certain fields

Tags: google-sheets

I'm not very experienced with Google Sheets, but I found a function here on Stack Overflow and modified it a bit to do almost everything I need:

```
=COUNT(FILTER('2014 Form Data'!$A:$A,'2014 Form Data'!$A:$A>=Tables!$A2 , '2014 Form Data'!$A:$A<='Tables'!$B2 ,TRIM('2014 Form Data'!$G:$G)=Tables!$D$2))
```

Where `'2014 Form Data'!$A:$A` contains a date and time-stamp, `Tables!A2` contains the start of a month and `Tables!B2` contains the last day of the month, and Tables!$D$2 contains the value I want to count from among all the time stamped entries for that month in the column 2014 `'Form Data'!$G:$G`. So basically, I get a result that says something like 5 entries from March had this particular value in this column.

It works great, I love it, but I'd like it to do one more thing...I'd like it to count instances of the text string in `Tables!$D$2`, even when there is other text present in the cells for `'2014 Form Data'!$G:$G`.

Any help on this issue will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please read the tag: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-spreadsheet/info

Comment: Why don't you share a doc with us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically, you are counting the rows where (among other conditions), the G column cell *is exactly* the text on `Tables!D2`. And, instead, you want to count where the G column cell *contains* the text on `Tables!D2`. Am I right?

You can do that with the following change to your formula. Replace:

```
TRIM('2014 Form Data'!$G:$G)=Tables!$D$2
```

With:

```
ISNUMBER(FIND(Tables!$D$2;'2014 Form Data'!$G:$G))
```